# Jaspersoft printing N number of subreports horizontally with dynamic/undefined data list and to be aligned with vertical columns

Tags: jasper-reports

the requirement is to print a report with some columns in vertical order and to concatenate a list of N number of subreports horizontally, 
with the ability to do multiple layers Header.

My example below showing that the years(2012, 2013) are headers and their values to be fetched dynamically while [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4] are static headers.

the section beneath 2012 to be repeated horizontally as per the number of years required to be included.
so it maybe 2012 or 2013,2014,...

So the table will be expanded in both ways Horizontally and vertically.

**my SQL data output is as below :**

[image: Data Source from mysql DB]

**My desired report output**

[image: Required report]

Please help if you can share the idea about how to get it implemented.

Comment: Looks like crosstab will help you

Comment: but, you know that crosstab is mandating row group/column group, and I think this won't work here